# question about Tetration

Tags: java, algorithm

i have question how write program  which  calculates   following procedures

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

i have exponential program which returns x^n here is code

```
public class Exp{
public static long  exp(long x,long n){
   long t=0;
 if (n==0){
     t= 1;
}
else{
       if (n %2==0){
   t=  exp(x,n/2)* exp(x,n/2);

}
else{

 t= x*exp(x,n-1);
}

}
 return t;
}


public static  void main(String[]args){
long x=5L;
long n=4L;
 System.out.println(exp(x,n));


}
}
```

but how use it in Tetration program?please help

Comment: no  i have not homework  never  i am studing  myself

Comment: davit-datuashvili fair enough.  Have fun, and +1 for your interesting problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tetration x ↑↑ n [can be defined recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Definition) as

```
x ↑↑ n  =  x ^ (x ↑↑ (n-1))
```

So you could write

```
long tetration(long x, long n) {
   if (n == 0)
     return 1;
   else
     return exp(x, tetration(x, n-1));
}
```

But notice that the tetration grows extremely fast, a `long` is will not be big enough to store even 4 ↑↑ 3 (= 1.3 × 10<sup>154</sup>). Perhaps you need a [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

(BTW, `exp` usually refers to the unary function *e<sup>x</sup>*, the binary function *x<sup>y</sup>* is usually called `pow`.)